# Cannot load offline image React Native using Expo Client iOS

Tags: image, react-native, expo, offline

I am not able to display an offline image using expo client on iOS in React Native, but it works perfectly on the web browser.

my app.json :

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*", "assets/*", "assets/fonts/*"
]
```

what i try to do :

```
<Image source={require('../assets/logo.svg')} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}/>
```

../assets because i'm in a component located in a folder "Components" :

```
assets
  logo.svg
Components
  MyComponent.js
App.js
app.json
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading .svg file
`react-native-svg` allows you to use SVGs in your app, with support for interactivity and animation.
so that you need to install

```
expo install react-native-svg
```

The implementation is provided by react-native-svg, and documentation is provided in this

[article.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/)

import the json into your app and use react-native-svg to render the svg like this:

```
 const json = require('./svg.json');
 render() {
    return (
      <Svg height={200} width={200} >
        <Path d={json['path']} />
      </Svg>
    );
  }
```

and another option, you can create an icon set from your svgs using IcoMoon, and then use it through
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons